# Changing route with react Router 4 from child

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with react router and its new update (version 4).

This is what im currently rendering:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <MainComponent/>

    <Link to="/firstchild" >This is a link</Link>

    <Rout path="/firstchild" component={FirstChild}/>
    <Route path="/secondchild" component={secondchild}/>

  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The first Link renders the FirstChild component, which is what its supposed to do.

But when i have a link within my FirstChild to route to the SecondChild component like this :

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/quelle">Link to SecondChild</Link>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

it changes the route, but the SecondChild component doesnt show up. Only after i go back and forth a page (alt+arrowLeft, alt+arrowRight) it loads the SecondChild.

So how do i create links in Child Components correctly, since i seem to fail horribly atm.

help is very appreciated! thanks

Comment: Are you aware that all links are absolute in react-router v4? You may expect your second link to point to `/firstchild/quelle`, but in fact, it points to `/quelle`.

Comment: lol i even used a wrong example. thanks for the help tho. solved it anyway